# How to attach a message to RSpec check?

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec, xunit

In RSpec: Can I attach a message to a check the same way as I would do in xUnit style test frameworks? How?

```ruby
assert_equal value1, value2, 'something is wrong'
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For RSpec 3+:

The message could be customized as a string or using a proc(check the reference).

```ruby
expect(1).to eq(2), 'one is not two!'
```

> Customized message
> RSpec tries to provide useful failure messages, but for cases in which you want more
> specific information, you can define your own message right in the example. This works for
> any matcher other than the operator matchers.

[source @ relishapp](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message)

---

For older RSpec versions

[`should`](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec/1.3.1/Kernel#should-instance_method) and [`should_not`](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec/1.3.1/Kernel#should_not-instance_method) take a second argument (`message`) that overrides the matcher’s default message.

```ruby
1.should be(2), 'one is not two!'
```

The default messages are usually pretty useful though.

Comment: How does one do it with `#should ==`?

Comment: @mohawkjohn: It seems like it would be something like `1.should(nil, 'one is not two!') == 2` (ick), but that does work because the `==` operator matcher looks like it always generates its own message.

Comment: you can also use `eq` instead of `==` i.e. `1.should eq(nil), 'one is not two!'`

Comment: is there no way of *appending to* the default message instead of *replacing* it ? the default message already provides the expected and actual values, all i want is to add the input to that

Answer (score 29):

In RSpec, it's the matcher's job to print a sensible failure message. The generic matchers that ship with RSpec can obviously only print generic non-descript failure messages, since they don't know anything about your particular domain. That's why it is recommended that you write your own domain-specific matchers, which will give you both more readable tests and more readable failure messages.

Here's an example from the [RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher):

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    (actual % expected).zero?
  end
  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would be a multiple of #{expected}"
  end
  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would not be a multiple of #{expected}"
  end
  description do
    "be multiple of #{expected}"
  end
end
```

Note: only `match` is required, the others will be generated automatically. However, the whole point of your question is of course that you do *not* like the default messages, so you need to at least also define `failure_message_for_should`.

Also, you can define `match_for_should` and `match_for_should_not` instead of `match` if you need different logic in the positive and negative case.

As @Chris Johnsen shows, you can also explicitly pass a message to the expectation. However, you run the risk of losing the readability advantages.

Compare this:

```
user.permissions.should be(42), 'user does not have administrative rights'
```

with this:

```
user.should have_administrative_rights
```

That would (roughly) be implemented like this:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_administrative_rights do
  match do |thing|
    thing.permissions == 42
  end
  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    'user does not have administrative rights'
  end
  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    'user has administrative rights'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that standard way of defining matchers is that easy. Though I prefer be "lazy": to factor out such things into separate named entities when they appear at least twice or remarkably simplify context where they are used.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was a problem of parenthesis:

```
        expect(coder.is_partial?(v)).to eq p, "expected #{v} for #{p}"
```

this resulted in a wrong number of arguments, while the correct way is:

```
        expect(coder.is_partial?(v)).to eq(p), "expected #{v} for #{p}"
```

Comment: Finaly I found this solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, that was it for me.  Using  `.to be(true)` .