# RSpec -- test if method called its block parameter

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec, call, block

I have a method that takes block of code as an argument. The problem is: how to test using RSpec if this method called the block?

The block may be evaluated in any scope the method needs, not necessarily using a `yield` or `block.call`. It be passed to another class, or evaluated it in an anonymous class object or somewhere else. For the test to pass it is enough to evaluate the block somewhere as a result of the method call.

Is there a way to test something like this using RSpec?

---

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279966/rspec-test-if-block-called-with-block-defined-in-before) for more complex case with `lets` and mocks.

Comment: Create a block with a side effect, like setting an enclosed variable our raising an exception, and check for the side effect?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Especially the concept with an exception is promising in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something like

```
a = 1
b.go { a = 2}
a.should == 2
```

Comment: This one works too! Simple and effective! Thanks ;-) Also added additional message to the `should` test to prevent confusion, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183656/how-to-attach-message-to-rspec-check)

Answer (score 3):

I like using `throw` instead of `raise` for this sort of problem, because it can't be rescued be an arbitrary rescue handler.  So it might look like this:

```
my_proc = proc { throw :my_proc_was_called }
expect {
  my_proc.call
}.to throw_symbol :my_proc_was_called
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dave Newton's suggestion in the comment above I did something like this:

```
 it "should run block defining the node" do
   message="This message is raised if block is properly evaluated."
   expect do
     node do
       raise message
     end 
   end.to raise_error message
 end
```

In case of error this prints message:

```
 Failure/Error: expect do
   expected Exception with "This message is raised if block is properly evaluated." but nothing was raised
```

Which I find informative enough.

Thanks again for help!