# how do I test that a ruby proc is called using rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test that a proc is called in an rspec spec.  The best I could come up with was this:

```
my_proc = proc { throw :my_proc_was_called }
expect {
  my_proc.call
}.to throw_symbol :my_proc_was_called
```

But this assumes that nothing else will catch my thrown symbol, plus I wouldn't mind a terser way to check arguments than by putting argument matchers inside the proc itself.  With rspec mocks, I can check that an object receives a method and even call the original method after checking the arguments, but I couldn't find any sort of convenience like that for a proc.

Chris Heald suggested just listening that the proc receives `call` but that breaks down if the block is invoked by yield as in this example:

```
my_class = Class.new do
  def call_proc
    yield
  end
end
my_proc = proc { }
expect(my_proc).to receive(:call)
my_class.new.call_proc(&my_proc)
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you're trying to test. You can't "test a proc", you need to test *outputs* from a proc. If that output is a thrown exception, your method is correct. Can't really help with such a vague requirement.

Comment: Why do you need to test if the proc came from rspec? At this point, you are testing the language, and not your application. This should not be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSpec -- test if method called its block parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249177/rspec-test-if-method-called-its-block-parameter)

Comment: My requirement is just to know that a proc was called.  I don't think it's vague.  It is like the block parameter example, but it's in this case it is not a block parameter.  I was just wondering if rspec supports any more syntactically readable format like a `expect(proc).to be_called` or something like that rather than having to rely on a throw (or a raise) as in the block parameter example.

Comment: Why not just `expect(my_proc).to receive(:call)`?

Comment: @ChrisHeald using `receive(:call)` doesn't work when the block gets called with `curry` though.